# Magento 1.9.0.1 - Error after Installation

Tags: magento-1.9

I installed Magento 1.9.0.1 and right after the Installation I've got the following error (it resultet in a 504 Gateway Timeout).

I've modified the index.php to get the real error, since no log has been written.

```
Error in file: "/kunden/123123123/webseiten/mage-test/app/code/core/Mage/Weee/sql/weee_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'intern_weee_tax' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `intern_weee_tax` (
  `value_id` int NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Value Id' ,
  `website_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Website Id' ,
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Entity Id' ,
  `country` varchar(2) NULL COMMENT 'Country' ,
  `value` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL default '0.0000' COMMENT 'Value' ,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '*' COMMENT 'State' ,
  `attribute_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Attribute Id' ,
  `entity_type_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity Type Id' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_INTERN_WEEE_TAX_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_INTERN_WEEE_TAX_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_INTERN_WEEE_TAX_COUNTRY` (`country`),
  INDEX `IDX_INTERN_WEEE_TAX_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_INTERN_WEEE_TAX_COUNTRY_INTERN_DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_COUNTRY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `intern_directory_country` (`country_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_INTERN_WEEE_TAX_ENTT_ID_INTERN_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `intern_catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_INTERN_WEEE_TAX_WEBSITE_ID_INTERN_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `intern_core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_INTERN_WEEE_TAX_ATTR_ID_INTERN_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `intern_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) COMMENT='Weee Tax' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

#0 /kunden/123123123/webseiten/mage-test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /kunden/123123123/webseiten/mage-test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.0')
#2 /kunden/123123123/webseiten/mage-test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.0')
#3 /kunden/123123123/webseiten/mage-test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /kunden/123123123/webseiten/mage-test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /kunden/123123123/webseiten/mage-test/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /kunden/123123123/webseiten/mage-test/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /kunden/123123123/webseiten/mage-test/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i suggest install magento again

Comment: Reinstalling issues this error again, so this is not a solution anyhow. :( Pretty bad that Mage has such errors in Mage2, too.

Comment: drop database and then reinstall

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

open your database go to `core_resource` tabel and in this entry `admin_setup` change `version` and `data version` to `1.6.1.2` for both value hope this will help you

Comment: It just changes the error. Now its `/webseiten/mage-test/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/sql/downloadable_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php` that makes the problems here.

Comment: hmm the sql that you install its old one or not match with your package , change all `version` and `data version` value in that table , for safer side take backup of that table

Comment: How can that be? I use the downloader.php from Magento itself.

Comment: have you installed database from theme providor??

Comment: if yes then then change value of all this `version` and `data version` in magento database

Comment: I've used the `downloader.php` from Magento itself. This script handles everything. Changing the values hasn't fixed the problem. :(

Comment: have you updated all versions manually as I suggested ??

Comment: Yes, to its siblings value, i.e. if version is 1.6.0.2.2 i've changed the data_version to the same value.

Comment: no  buddy set `version` and `data version` to `1.6.1.2` only

Comment: No I've got `Error in file: "/kunden/280924_80336/webseiten/mage-test/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/data/reports_setup/data-install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `mg1_report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`) VALUES (?, ?)` :O